# Xcode 6.1 Becomes Unresponsive when I open the storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

When i open the story board in my xcode 6.1, Xcode become un responsive and if I force quit the xcode it gives the following error message Any help would be appriciated thanks in advance

```
Date/Time:       2015-03-18 17:55:36 +0530
OS Version:      10.10.2 (Build 14C1510)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  21

Command:         Xcode
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
Build Version:   2
Project Name:    IDEFrameworks
Source Version:  6528000000000000
Parent:          launchd [1]
PID:             525

Event:           hang
Duration:        1.00s (process was unresponsive for 22 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           11 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  Macmini5,1
Active cpus:     4

Fan speed:       1802 rpm

--------------------------------------------------
Timeline format: stacks are sorted chronologically
Use -i and -heavy to re-report with count sorting
--------------------------------------------------
```

When I do the same in Xcode 6.1.1 I am getting the following Error

```
Date/Time:       2015-03-18 19:01:10 +0530
OS Version:      10.10.2 (Build 14C1510)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  21

Command:         Xcode
Path:            /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Version:         6.1.1 (6611)
Build Version:   4
Project Name:    IDEFrameworks
Source Version:  6611000000000000
Parent:          launchd [1]
PID:             1344

Event:           hang
Duration:        1.80s (process was unresponsive for 38 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           19 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  Macmini5,1
Active cpus:     4

Fan speed:       4312 rpm

--------------------------------------------------
Timeline format: stacks are sorted chronologically
Use -i and -heavy to re-report with count sorting
--------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Xcode 6.0.1 rather than Xcode 6.1. If possible, please update to the latest Xcode (6.2 currently).

If you can't, sometimes this issue happens when someone opens the storyboard/xib in a newer Xcode version and commits those changes. If you use any type of cvs, try to check the log on the file or even revert it to a previous state.

Comment: When I open the Story board in Xcode 6.1  I am facing same Xcode freeze

Answer (score 0):

Okay don't hit me in the face for saying this, but my Xcode often crashes when it is running in fullscreen. Simply going in windowed mode (and dragging to the edge to mimic the fullscreen effect) resolved most of my crashes.

Thanks to my boss for letting me work on a toaster.

Though I don't expect this to  be your issue, this moved fixed a LOT of crashes for me.